# Why does sorting an associative array by a boolean value using a comparison function reverse the array order?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, comparison

I have an associative array:

```
    Array(

        [110] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-15 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [128] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [129] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [130] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [132] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [123] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-07-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [124] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-07-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [125] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-07-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [127] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-07-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
     )
```

Generally this should be sorted by `releaseDate` but the elements for which `isNewest` is true should come first.

I use `uasort()` to accomplish that:

```
    uasort($arr, function($a, $b){
        return $a['isNewest'] - $b['isNewest'];
    });
```

Sometimes `isNewest` will be true but in this example (and in the data conditions i first discovered this bug) `isNewest` is `false` for all entries.

Running the above, this is the result:

```
Array
    (
        [124] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-07-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [125] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-07-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [127] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-07-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [123] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-07-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [132] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [128] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [129] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
        [130] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-01 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )

        [110] => Array
            (
                [releaseDate] => 2020-08-15 00:00:00
                [isNewest] => 
            )
    )
```

The problem is that sorting the array the way i do it, using `uasort()` seems to reverse the array order. If you look at the above two arrays and check the `releaseDate`, you will see what i mean.

If `isNewest` were true for any entries, they'd come first, but the rest of the array order would still end up being reversed.

I seem to have some trouble understanding how the `uasort()` comparison function works. I tried returning `-1` and `1` and even flipped the `$a` and `$b` parameters, but to no avail.

What am i doing wrong here? How can i use `uasort()` properly here, so that the array remains sorted by `releaseDate` in descending order, but in such a way that entries that have `isNewest` set to `true` come first?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single [`uasort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) call to sort your data, checking first whether the dates are equal (if not, returning that sort result) and then sorting the `true` values first:

```
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    // if dates not equal, return result of comparison
    // since dates are in Y-m-d H:i:s format we can compare as strings
    if (($rdcmp = strcmp($a['releaseDate'], $b['releaseDate'])) != 0) return $rdcmp;
    // dates are equal, so sort true values first
    if ($a['isNewest'] && !$b['isNewest']) return -1;
    elseif (!$a['isNewest'] && $b['isNewest']) return 1;
    else return 0;
});
print_r($array);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PNQmR)

Or to sort all `true` values before `false`, and then sort by `releaseDate`, you can use this code:

```
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    // sort true values first
    if ($a['isNewest'] && !$b['isNewest']) return -1;
    elseif (!$a['isNewest'] && $b['isNewest']) return 1;
    // boolean values are equal, so sort by date. 
    // Since dates are in Y-m-d H:i:s format, we can sort as strings
    else return strcmp($a['releaseDate'], $b['releaseDate']);
});
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LoN4W)

Note that if you want to sort by `releaseDate` descending you should change

```
strcmp($a['releaseDate'], $b['releaseDate'])
```

to

```
strcmp($b['releaseDate'], $a['releaseDate'])
```

Note also that *if* your boolean values are actually `true` and `false`, you can simplify the boolean compare to

```
return $b['isNewest'] - $a['isNewest'];
```

Otherwise, since PHP treats all sorts of values as `true` (including negative numbers, which could mess up sorting by a subtraction), it's safer to do the specific compare as I have done in the code block.

Comment: `strcmp(!$b['isNewest'] . $b['releaseDate'], !$a['isNewest'] . $a['releaseDate'])` works fine too :)

Comment: @Pilan that would sort by `isNewest` and then `releaseDate`, but OP wants the opposite. Also `false` interpreted as a string is the empty string `''`, so you'd potentially be comparing part of the `releaseDate` with a `1` (if one `isNewest` was `false` and the other `true`).

Comment: Yes, you are right i missed that. Here the fixed one: `strcmp(intval($b['isNewest']) . $b['releaseDate'], intval($a['isNewest']) . $a['releaseDate'])`. - `isNewest` come first, as OP wanted. Thats what i assumed, but OP may have meant that `isNewest` has to come first for every group.

Comment: @Pilan the question isn't really clear. I've interpreted it as wanting to sort by `releaseDate`, and for a given `releaseDate`, the entries with `isNewest = true` should come first.

Comment: Actually, sorry for the confusion, but yes, i need `isNewest` elements to always come first, no matter what. But those entries and all others need to be sorted by releaseDate in a descending order.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear in my question. This is the right answer. The comments were extra helpful! Thank you.

Comment: @SquareCat I've updated the answer with code to sort by the `isNewest` values first as well.

Answer (score 0):

I cant [reproduce](https://3v4l.org/GHlvt) the reversal when every `isNewest` is set to `false`.

To get your desired result of first(`isNewest`) and second(`releaseDate`) order sort, you can simply use `uasort` twice - use highest priority sort last.

```
uasort($input, fn($a, $b) => strtotime($b['releaseDate']) - strtotime($a['releaseDate']));
uasort($input, fn($a, $b) => $b['isNewest'] - $a['isNewest']);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/l4XJH).

---

You can use [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort) too in case you dont need the keys. (numeric keys will be lost).

```
array_multisort(
    array_column($input, 'isNewest'),
    SORT_DESC, // 1 before 0 (true before false)
    array_column($input, 'releaseDate'),
    SORT_DESC,
    $input
);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/VqoGW).

---

Tip for the future. Use [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to post data here. So we can simply copy/paste it to use it in code.

---

In case you want to have the `isRelease=true` candidates at first place in every sub-group (`releaseDate`) - flip the `uasort`s, or `array_columns` in `array_multisort`.

Comment: Calling `uasort()` twice just sorts by the second condition, not by both conditions.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry no, here the [proof](https://3v4l.org/hCskM).

Comment: It might work sometimes, but it's not guaranteed to work. PHP sorting is not stable.

Comment: @Barmar When i recall right the stability of a sort refers to the elements which have the same values being compared - only for this elements there is no defined rule which should come first. But in this context this seem irrelevant to me, am i missing something?

Comment: That's exactly the point. If you sort the array twice by different criteria, and there are elements that are the same in the second criteria, they won't necessarily stay in the order that the first sort produced.

Comment: I see. I've looked up the source, as far as i can tell for `uasort` a stable sort is used: [`php_array_user_compare`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L1019) - more [info](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/e12b9df05d238ec0f3cf47b28a49a4df1b1e3442) - php8 though :/

Comment: That's only a few months ago. What version of PHP is it in? Most people probably won't be using that version.

Comment: 8 didnt know that, thx for the lesson :)